# display images which are stored in Google Drive on a public website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-drive-api

if its possible to access/display files like images which are stored in Google Drive on a public website.

Answer (score 0):

no, but you can publicly share them and provide links to them.

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2494886&p=visibility_options